# Interview Preparation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, interview, qa-process

How can prepare for quality automation analyst (1 yr exp) interview? Actually this is the final round. They've said like there will be a technical discussion and soft skills with the QA lead and Director. So, I'm really confused and nervous. The machine test and F2f technical section had completed, as that is the first round.

So, guys, can anyone please guide me which all the topics that I should cover? I have overall of 2 yr exp in testing (1 each in manual and automation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just be yourself. They asked you to the final round, so they see potential in you.
Swamping yourself with more topics and information might overwhelm you more than it benefits.

The interviewers will look at you someone with 2 years of experience, not a guru/expert/god/know-it-all.

Be honest, and saying I don't know is an good option to most questions. I don't know, but this would be the path I take to research it.

Show you are [proactive](https://www.franklincovey.com/the-7-habits/habit-1.html). Read into [how to improve as a QA in general](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/39054/how-to-further-expand-knowledge-in-software-qa) and show you take steps towards mastery in the interview. I just experimented with X, or read this concept in book Y.

Comment: Thank you for the advice sir

Answer (score 2):

From Automation point of view following things are important:

- Logic
- OOPs concept
- Any language hands-on

From Manual testing point of view following things are important:

- Basic understanding of testing terminologies
- Development cycle & Testing cycle
- Bug Reporting
- Testing skills

From Behavioral point of view following things are important:

- Attitude towards work
- Attitude towards team and team members
- 'Student for life' mindset
- Positive approach

Apart from these, as Niels mentioned, please be yourself and honest with your answers. If you don't know anything it's absolutely fine to convey it directly. Be confident with your answers.

All the best Albin K S.